# In what (semantic) context might "REFUSE" be used with a gerund complement?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, gerunds, complements

I know that, prescriptively speaking, that the verb "refuse" is supposed to be followed by an infinitive. For example:

*The parents refused to buy the dangerous toy for their kid.*

Since language usage isn't clear cut, I was wondering whether using a gerund instead of infinitive would be acceptable at all as in the following sentence:

*The parents refused buying the dangerous toy for their kid.* *

Answer (score 2):

You can refuse a *noun* ("She refused the medicine they offered."), and a gerund is technically a noun ("Reading is fundamental") but I cannot think of a single example of refusing a gerund that does not sound awkward or just plain wrong.

Your example, "The parents refused buying the dangerous toy for their kid", would be in the latter category.  "Buying a toy" as an action is not being offered to the parents.  They are being asked to do it and they demur.  That takes the infinitive.

Comment: I agree - *to refuse* + gerund sounds inherently "awkward" to me too. But although some of the written instances of [***refused giving it***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22refused+giving+it%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) either do or should have a comma before a supplementary clause starting with ***giving*** , a lot of them are for the usage in question. I also have the feeling it was more common a century or two ago, despite the fact that I think in general gerunds were *less* common then.

Comment: This from 1876: [*They ... are even sturdy enough Nonconformists **to refuse bowing** at the mere mention of the name of Jesus*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+refuse+bowing+at%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- but 140 years later, doesn't it sound like the Nonconformists were somehow offered "bowing" as a service?  "Oh, would you like us to bow for you?"  "No, thanks, we're Nonconformists."

Comment: If the question had been asked on ELL I'd simply have advised OP to avoid the usage. But ELU isn't here to teach non-native speakers how to use English "naturally" - it's for those of us who already *know* what constitutes a "happy" usage to discuss the finer points (in the context of this type of question, at least). Personally, I don't have a problem even today with *Although in principle I **reject spoiling** my ballot paper, with such a poor list of candidates I may have no choice*. Using ***refuse*** there sounds "dated" to me, rather than "ungrammatical".

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- yes, that was my point.  Sorry if I did not make that clear.  It is grammatically correct: you can refuse a noun just like you can reject a noun, it just sounds funny because semantically, we don't tend to "refuse" gerunds.  Refusing a noun means you decline to accept it and there aren't many situations where you are offered gerunds.  More abstract verbs like *reject*, *enjoy*, and *practice* work on a wider scope.

Comment: No, your position seems quite clear to me (it's grammatical, but not common in normal English). My point is simply that from the perspective of a learner, it's unlikely any general principle could be identified. *I like swimming, I like to swim, I enjoy swimming, I refuse to swim*, are all fine, but *I enjoy to swim* never is in my idiolect, and *I refuse swimming* is at the very least "unlikely". There are similar usage differences with ***despise, dislike***, for example, and I can't see any basis in semantics or grammar for the preferences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with your view which made me post this inquiry in the first place. As far as I'm concerned, regardless of the gerund-similar-to-noun-thing, refuse + verb-ing is not a grammatically proper complement of the verb and usually is used with to-infintive instead.

Comment: = Prescriptively, with regard to infinitive/gerund complements, verbs usually take one of 4 cases: (1) verbs that take infinitive exclusively (e.g.want, need, REFUSE), (2) verbs that take gerund exclusively (e.g., enjoy, avoid, risk), (3) verbs that take either complement with little or no change in the meaning (e.g. like, try, start), (4) verbs that take either complement with big change in the meaning (e.g., stop, remember, forget).

Comment: = However, from a descriptive view, languages change and sometimes things aren't that clear cut when it comes to real life usage. The point that it's "odd" rather than "ungrammatical" and justifying ruling out the "non-grammaticality" issue because it's essentially a noun would make someone accept this complement with other verbs such as "need buying, want buying" as well, would you?

Comment: @Linguister: I don't really think *descriptive/prescriptive* is a very useful distinction here. I can't believe even the most diehard prescriptivist has made up an exhaustive list specifying which of your categories each possible verb falls into, but even someone *did*, the next prescriptivist would likely dispute some of the classifications. Saying *John needs buying* would normally imply he's some kind of "slave", and that he (or someone/something) requires that he be bought. But I can't deny it *could* mean it's necessary that John should get some "retail therapy".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here is the thing, aside from the prescriptive/descriptive distinction, while the general question is about refuse + gerund, it's more specifically about refuse in the given example above. You're right, sometimes you can use a gerund with verb that usually takes an infinitive as in your example of "need buying". However, in your example as well as "the house needs cleaning", the complements have more of an intransitive meaning than a transitive one as in "John needs buying the house" which can be more comparable to the example of given in the question of "refuse buying the toy".

Comment: I found an online page explaining the two possibilities being dependent on the action in terms of whether it actually happens or not:"the parents refused buying the toy" = the action takes place , but "the parents refused to buy the toy" = the action doesn't take place. What do you think?

Comment: @Linguister: That looks like a totally spurious distinction to me. But assuming whoever made the claim is indeed a native speaker, I might be better able to figure out *why* they came up with such a curious misconception if you could provide the link.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll help, it was in the context of misuse with little explanation. Here you go under number (11): http://mle20132014.blogspot.com/2013/11/lesson-notes-main-mistakes-correction.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.really-learn-english.com/verbs-followed-only-by-infinitives.html -- Here is a list of verbs that can only be followed by infinitives (and not gerunds.) Refuse is on the list.